# How can I get more information on an invalid DOM element through the Validator?

Tags: java, xml, xml-validation

I am validating an in-memory DOM object using the `javax.xml.validation.Validator` class against an XSD schema. I am getting a `SAXParseException` being thrown during the validation whenever there is some data corruption in the information I populate my DOM from.

An example error:

> org.xml.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '???"??[?????G?>???p~tn??~0?1]' is not a valid valud for 'hexBinary'.

What I am hoping is that there is a way to find the location of this error in my in-memory DOM and print out the offending element and its parent element. My current code is:

```
public void writeDocumentToFile(Document document) throws XMLWriteException {
  try {
    // Validate the document against the schema
    Validator validator = getSchema(xmlSchema).newValidator();
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));

    // Serialisation logic here.

  } catch(SAXException e) {
    throw new XMLWriteException(e); // This is being thrown
  } // Some other exceptions caught here.
}

private Schema getSchema(URL schema) throws SAXException {
  SchemaFactory schemaFactory = 
    SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

  // Some logic here to specify a ResourceResolver

  return schemaFactory.newSchema(schema);
}
```

I have looked into the `Validator#setErrorHandler(ErrorHandler handler)` method but the `ErrorHandler` interface only gives me exposure to a `SAXParseException` which only exposes the line number and column number of the error. Because I am using an in-memory DOM this returns -1 for both line and column number.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't really want to have to manually validate the Strings before I add them to the DOM if the libraries provide me the function I'm looking for.

I'm using JDK 6 update 26 and JDK 6 update 7 depending on where this code is running.

EDIT: With this code added -

```
validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
  @Override
  public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
    printException(exception);
    throw exception;
  }

  @Override
  public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
    printException(exception);
    throw exception;
  }

  @Override
  public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
    printException(exception);
    throw exception;
  }

  private void printException(SAXParseException exception) {
    System.out.println("exception.getPublicId() = " + exception.getPublicId());
    System.out.println("exception.getSystemId() = " + exception.getSystemId());
    System.out.println("exception.getColumnNumber() = " + exception.getColumnNumber());
    System.out.println("exception.getLineNumber() = " + exception.getLineNumber());
  }
});
```

I get the output:

```
exception.getPublicId() = null
exception.getSystemId() = null
exception.getColumnNumber() = -1
exception.getLineNumber() = -1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Xerces (the Sun JDK default), you can get the element that failed validation through the [http://apache.org/xml/properties/dom/current-element-node](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/properties.html#dom.current-element-node) property:

```
...
catch (SAXParseException e)
{
    Element curElement = (Element)validator.getProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/dom/current-element-node");

    System.out.println("Validation error: " + e.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Element: " + curElement);
}
```

Example:

```
String xml = "<root xmlns=\"http://www.myschema.org\">\n" +
             "<text>This is text</text>\n" +
             "<number>32</number>\n" +
             "<number>abc</number>\n" +
             "</root>";

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
Schema schema = getSchema(getClass().getResource("myschema.xsd"));

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
try
{
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(doc));
}
catch (SAXParseException e)
{
    Element curElement = (Element)validator.getProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/dom/current-element-node");

    System.out.println("Validation error: " + e.getMessage());
    System.out.println(curElement.getLocalName() + ": " + curElement.getTextContent());

    //Use curElement.getParentNode() or whatever you need here
}
```

If you need to get line/column numbers from the DOM, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915422/get-line-number-from-xml-node-java) has a solution to that problem.

Comment: Hrmm, thanks for the detailed answer. I am getting `org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Property 'http://apache.org/xml/properties/dom/current-element-node' is not recognized.` under JDK 1.6 update 7. I assume accessing this property doesn't require internet access?

Comment: @Bringer128 I'm running under Java 1.6.0u25 and it works.  It may have been a Xerces property that was added recently.  It might be possible if you have to run under an old JDK 1.6 to bundle a later version of Xerces with your app and use DocumentBuilderFactory/Validator implementations from that instead of the JDK default.

Comment: You're right, it works under Java 1.6.0u26 too. This appears to be what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to do this when a DTD file is being used to validate the XML?

Answer (score 0):

SaxParseException exposes the SystemId and PublicId. Does that not give you enough information?

Comment: I've updated my question. The validator appears to be returning null for those two values, so they're not of much use.