# How to get error details from JAXB Validator?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, schema

I have some classes with JAXB annotations, I have created some instances and I need to validate them against my XSD files. I should be able to get the details of what is wrong when the objects are invalid.

So far I haven't had luck, I know about this class ValidationEventHandler but apperantly I can use it with the Unmarshaller class, the problem is that I have to validate the objects not the raw XML.

I have this code:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("x.y.z");
JAXBSource jaxbSource = new JAXBSource(jaxbContext, myObject);
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory
                .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("mySchema.xsd"));
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

validator.validate(jaxbSource);
```

This code will work, it will validate the object and throw an exception with the message, something like this:

> cvc-pattern-valid: Value '12345678901' is not facet-valid with respect
>   to pattern '\d{10}' for type 'id'.]

The problem is that I need specific details, with a string like that I would have to parse all the messages.

Comment: One possible option exists here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921190/how-to-get-the-element-of-and-invalid-xml-file-with-failed-xsd-validation

Comment: Found another awnser that shows you how to get the actual invalid DOM element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077437/how-can-i-get-more-information-on-an-invalid-dom-element-through-the-validator#answer-8162185

Answer (score 1):

You can set an instance of `ErrorHandler` on the `Validator` to catch individual errors:

```
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
    validator.validate(source);
```

**MyErrorHandler**

Below is a sample implementation of the `ErrorHandler` interface.  If you don't rethrow the exception the validation will continue.

```
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("\nWARNING");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("\nERROR");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("\nFATAL ERROR");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html

Comment: Hi @blaise The only problem that I have with this approach is that all I get is a string with all the details like "cvc-pattern-valid: Value '12345678901' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '\d{10}' for type 'id'.]"... Since I need to know what specific element is wrong I have no other option but parse the string

Answer (score 1):

I. If you validate a complex object hierarchy, you can create the Marshaller yourself and set its listener:

```
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setListener(yourListener);
JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(marshaller, object);
```

This listener will get notified with instances of your objects as it walks the hierarchy.

II. Add an `ErrorHandler` from the other answer. At least with Wildfly 15 the messages look like:

> cvc-maxInclusive-valid: Value '360.953674' is not facet-valid with respect to maxInclusive '180.0' for type '#AnonType_longitudeGeographicalPosition'.'
> cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '360.953674' of element 'longitude' is not valid.'

So you can parse out the element name, which is the guilty terminal field name.

III. Combine I and II with some introspection and you can reconstruct a full Java Beans style path to the erroneous field if necessary.