# XmlBeans source locator during reading/writing

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xmlbeans

I have XmlBeans classes generated from an XSD. I would like to track line numbers for the persisted objects. Is this possible? I don't care if this information is stored during parsing (xml → beans) or during prettyprinting (beans → xml) because I keep them in synch in my application flow.

I would like start and end line/column numbers, if possible.

I don't care if I have to use some kind of non-standard hack to get to the locator data.

If there is another Java XML framework that can generate classes from an XSD file *and* support locator data, then I'm willing to switch.

Comment: Can you clarify your question with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [XmlOptions#setLoadLineNumbers()](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.html#setLoadLineNumbers%28%29), for example:

```
MyDocument.Factory.parse(xmlFile, new XmlOptions().setLoadLineNubmers());
```

Then to retrieve the line numbers from the xml store, find the nearest XmlLineNumber bookmark.

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans.*;

public class linenumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws XmlException
    {
        XmlOptions options = new XmlOptions().setLoadLineNumbers();
        XmlObject xobj = XmlObject.Factory.parse("<a>\n<b>test</b>\n<c>test</c>\n</a>", options);

        // let's get the line number for the '<c>' xml object
        XmlObject cobj = xobj.selectPath(".//c")[0];
        System.out.println(cobj.xmlText());

        XmlCursor c = null;
        try
        {
            c = cobj.newCursor();

            // search for XmlLineNumber bookmark
            XmlLineNumber ln =
                (XmlLineNumber) c.getBookmark( XmlLineNumber.class );

            if (ln == null)
                ln = (XmlLineNumber) c.toPrevBookmark( XmlLineNumber.class );

            if (ln != null)
            {
                int line = ln.getLine();
                int column = ln.getColumn();
                int offset = ln.getOffset();

                System.out.println("line=" + line + ", col=" + column + ", offset=" + offset);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (c != null) c.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but then how would you access the line number for a given object?

Comment: I've updated the sample code showing how to retrieve the bookmarks.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

> If there is another Java XML framework that can generate classes from
>   an XSD file and support locator data, then I'm willing to switch.

JAXB can generate classes from an XML schema, and below are a couple of ways you could get the location information.  For a comparison of JAXB and XMLBeans see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xmlbeans.html

**OPTION #1 - StAX and Unmarshaller.Listener**

***Demo***

```
package forum10241929;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource(new File("src/forum10241929/input.xml")));

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setListener(new LocationListener(xsr));
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
    }

    private static class LocationListener extends Unmarshaller.Listener {

        private XMLStreamReader xsr;

        public LocationListener(XMLStreamReader xsr) {
            this.xsr = xsr;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) {
            log("End", target);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) {
            log("Start", target);
        }

        private void log(String event, Object target) {
            System.out.print(event);
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(target);
            System.out.print(" [");
            Location location = xsr.getLocation();
            System.out.print(location.getLineNumber());
            System.out.print(",");
            System.out.print(location.getColumnNumber());
            System.out.println("]");
        }

    }

}
```

***input.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <address>
        <street>1 A Street</street>
    </address>
</customer>
```

***Output***

```
Start forum10241929.Customer@144aa0ce [2,11]
Start forum10241929.Address@19e3cd51 [4,14]
End forum10241929.Address@19e3cd51 [6,15]
End forum10241929.Customer@144aa0ce [7,12]
```

***Customer***

```
package forum10241929;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private Address address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

***Address***

```
package forum10241929;

public class Address {

    private String street;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

}
```

**OPTION #2 - @XmlLocation**

There is a JAXB extension that is supported by both EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) and the reference implementation called `@XmlLocation` (below is an Example using MOXy).  This will only capture the start location.

```
package forum10241929;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlLocation;
import org.xml.sax.Locator;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private Address address;

    @XmlLocation
    private Locator location;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will mark this as answered, even though I have since implemented a different solution, based on the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915422/get-line-number-from-xml-node-java
Basically, I first parse into a regular DOM tree while preserving location information as user data, and then I feed that DOM tree to XmlBeans. This gives me correct start and end information.