# How to get the xml line number of an object parsed using eclipse emf modeling

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, emf

I am developing some tool using eclipse emf modeling and I would like to know how to get the xml line number of an parsed object. I need this in order to create file problem markers during data validation. I read some topics about this but I couldn't find the information I was looking for. I was thinking that maybe somebody can help me with some hints regarding how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if EMF provides this feature.

I haven't tried it but would start looking into how you can customize the XML deserialization process. It's possible to [store the line number of each XML DOM node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915422/get-line-number-from-xml-node-java) during de-serialization process. With [`XMLResource.getDOMHelper()`](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/xmi/XMLResource.html#getDOMHelper()) you should be able to build a mapping between XML nodes and EMF objects. Using this mapping it should be possible to associate each EMF object with a line in XML file.